# Incorrect tag used to zap a question by the golden badge hammer

Tags: support, design, close-reasons, dupehammer

I found this strange thing which is IMHO a bug:

[image]

The problem is that **egreg** zapped the question using his golden [xetex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xetex) badge.  However, the question isn't tagged [xetex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xetex), it had the tag but lost it before **egreg** voted on it. Sure **egreg** could zap the question anyways using his golden [symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbols) badge.

The question is, whether the system used the correct golden badge and displayed the wrong one, or used the wrong one directly. Or is it [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) that the original tags are considered when zapping the question by the golden badge hammer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The notorious [dupehammer gives superpowers to learned members of the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254589/914686), but [here are the rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/168244):

> - You can instantly close as a duplicate any question that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.
> - You can instantly reopen any question closed as a duplicate that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.
> - You can only close or reopen a given question once (this hasn't changed).
> - If you get in a fight with someone over whether a question should be closed, moderators will be notified and they'll <s>hit everyone with hammers</s> lock everything down and tell you to go home.

The first point is emphasized later in the same linked "rule-post":

> ... If a question has a tag where you have a gold badge, and it was part of the *original* set of tags applied to the question, you can mark it as a duplicate with a single vote.

Therefore this is, as you mentioned, [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: Thanks, I missed this. I changed this from [meta-tag:bug] to [meta-tag:support] to remove it from the bug list.